# C# How do i split an array into two

Tags: c#

I havent found any clear ones yet and can figure out how to split it the current array is formatted like 10000,56 and would like it to split the so all the data on the left is split from the right

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ;
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                inputFile = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                string[] marks = new string[4];
                int count = 0;
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    marks[count] = inputFile.ReadLine();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(marks[count]);

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Marks loaded");
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question. As it is now, it is hardly legible what your problem is.

Comment: Okay sorry on my part

Comment: What array do you even want to split? Your `marks` array?

Comment: Or do you actually want to split a string? `inputFile.ReadLine().Split(',');` ?

Comment: @Harry, Some tips for asking your question. Try making this info clear: Is "10000,56" a line in the text file that you are reading? Are there more than one line in that file? What is the "left" and the "right"? Do you want to separate based on the comma?

Comment: I want to split my marks array that current array when listed on a listbox is formated as 10000,56 and would like to split it

Comment: 10000,56 is a line in a text file that is being read and i would like to separte it from the comma so all the before the comma is split from the data after the comma

Comment: Just a wild gues when you say split do you actually mean to insert white spaces? So `10000,56` should be displayed as `10000 , 56` ?

Comment: No no like split it so for example that 56 value is in a new array from the 10000

Comment: My last guess for the day - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1PUQRg

Comment: Mate your a lad exactly what i needed may god bless you with eternal living

Answer (score 3):

Trying to answer unclear question

You can read the entire line as string, and then split it:

```
string[] words = phrase.Split(',');
```

or if you have array you can find the char you want to split with

This is with LINQ :

```
char[] x = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
var index = x.Select((c, i) => new {c, i}).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Equals('D')).i
```

with array class:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(x, c=> c.Equals('E'));
```

and split by index

```
public void Split<T>(T[] array, int index, out T[] first, out T[] second) {
  first = array.Take(index).ToArray();
  second = array.Skip(index).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: 10000,43
10001,26
10002,43
10003,57
10004,100
10005,57
10006,55
10007,60
10008,37
10009,30
10010,50
10011,17
10012,59
10013,57
10014,27 this is how the array is formatted so do any of these methods just separate that 2 digit value and put it into a separate array they

Comment: You can achieve expected result by this :  List<string> marklst = new List<string>(); for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++) { string[] values = marks[i].Split(','); marklst.AddRange(values); }     Hope this will help